# git over ssh second user can't clone

Tags: linux, git, ssh

We are two developers working on a project and I set a git repository on a server (ArchLinux) we both have access over ssh. The git repository was created the following way :

```
mkdir project
touch project/readme.txt

git init project
cd projet
git add .
git commit -m 'initial commit'
git push origin master
cd ..
git clone --bare project.git

cd project.git
git config core.sharedRepository true

cd ..
setfacl -R -m g:<group name>:rwX project.git
find gitrepo -type d | xargs setfacl -R -m d:g:<group name>:rwX
```

our group name is dev and both users are in the group (checked in /etc/groups)

On a second machine (can be mine or the second developer's), we clone the repository this way.

```
git clone user1@ip:/path/project.git (over ssh)
password: <enter user1 password>
```

Everything is put inside a folder project. This user can now do add, push, pull etc.

Then we try the second user

```
git clone user2@ip:/path/project.git (over ssh)
password: <enter user2 password>
```

and we get this

```
fatal: '/path/project.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

We can connect the second user with SSH with no problem so it's not a bad password. Do you have any idea why we encounter this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you did not set up [`git deamon`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Git-Daemon)

Read the whole page (its a short one) and follow the steps.
Don't skip the part where you define which projects can be shared.

Comment: I did stop at 4.4 in that book (got the paper version). I'll read this and come back with my feedback.